# Microsoft flow not filtering SharePoint list by date to send email

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

First thing first I am very new to Microsoft Flow and think I may have bit off more than I can chew.

I have a SharePoint list with multiple dates that I plan on using to send communication.  I would like FLOW to examine my SharePoint list and for each record where Today's Date matches the "T-21" date send an email. T-21 date in SharePoint is Date only format.

Now I figured out to use a trigger, get the items from my SharePoint list, but the problem I am having is the filter/date compare.

Used Compose to format utcnow to "M/d/yyyy" format so it matches my SharePoint list.  But either I get an error message or the FLOW ignores the filter/date compare and sends everyone an email even those where "t-21" does not match.

- Trigger
- Compose (format utcnow)
- Get Items from SharePoint list (Filter query??)
- Condition (T-21 = Compose Date from earlier; NOT WORKING)
- If yes, send email
- If no, do nothing

Hopefully this explains things.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following post I stumbled upon while I was trying to set up my flows. This person has the same use case as you, in that they trigger something based upon the date. There is code included in the post as well to help you solve the date condition problem you're having.
The link: [Post explaining possible solution to your question](https://medium.com/@smcollier/using-flow-to-post-todays-events-from-sharepoint-to-teams-964f5fd2407c)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The date compare function is exactly what I needed.

Here is my working formula for condition that compares T-21 date with utcNow:
@equals(substring(items('Apply_to_each')?['T_x002d_21'], 0, 10), utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd'))

Thanks again @chriscam85

Comment: What I learned about comparing dates in Microsoft Flow is that they have to be in the same format otherwise the condition will not work.  Substring is used to grab first first 10 characters of the date from SharePoint list.  In the utcNow expression you can also set the format.